# Color scheme problem with the "Favorite tag" dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

When trying to choose a favorite tag, the color scheme prevents me from actually seeing the selected tag:

[image: invisible text]

Comment: This appears to be a problem in Chrome (windows & mac) and Firefox (mac, didn't test windows), but not in Safari (latest).